# Python. Number inserting

Tags: python

trying to make a program that says, when it's an estonian post code or not. Estonian post code has 5 numbers. first number is between 1 and 9. Other four numbers are between 0 and 9. My code at the moment:

```
print("insert postcode")
    inserted_code = input()

if (inserted_code[0] > "0" and inserted_code[1-4] >= "0"):

    print("Estonian postcode")

elif (inserted_code[0] == "0"):

    print("Not an estonian code")

else:
    print("Not an estonian code")
```

My question is, how can I mak it that way, that the program knows that Estonian post code has 5 numbers?

Comment: Why not just test that `code >= 10000 and code <= 99999`? Or if it absolutely needs to be a string, use a regex, e.g. `/[1-9]\d{4}/`.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, then it doesen't say that Estonian code has 5 numbers? Or does it? Sorry, I've been on Python for  2 weeks or so only.

Comment: What do you think `inserted_code[1-4]` does? It does *not* look at characters 2-5...

Comment: @MartinRehkli Which number hasn't got 5 digits and is smaller than 10,000 or greater than 99,999?

Comment: inserted_code[1-4] > "0"

Thought it tells that numbers 1-4 must be bigger or equal 0. Ye sorry, my mistake, i forgot to add equals symbol.  :D

Comment: @MartinRehkli `> "0"` does *not* mean ‘is a digit’. Note that `":" > "0"` → `True`, `"?" > "0"` → `True`, etc.

Comment: Thank you guys for help. I'm going to try how to get it like I want it. 

Cheers!

Comment: You need to first check to see whether or not the code is an integer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36136484/python-3-1-problems-with-else-in-my-code/36136619#36136619 then you can check the range (see my answer to the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to match against special regular expression - template which postcode should match.

```
    inserted_code = input("insert postcode")
    import re
    if re.match('^[1-9][0-9]{4}$', inserted_code): 
       print("Estonian postcode")
    else:
       print("Not an estonian code")
```

Comment: This is the code, I was trying myself a bit time ago, but made some small mistakes. This works. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you doing this:

1. use `input("text")` instead `print` description before each `input()`
2. `inserted_code[1:]` stand for every char except very first one
3. please, check that length of code equals 5 chars.

> ```
>   inserted_code = input("insert postcode")
>   if int(inserted_code[0]) > 0 and all([int(last_num) >= 0 for last_num in inserted_code[1:]]) and len(inserted_code) == 5:
>       print("Estonian postcode")
>   else:
>       print("Probably, Belarusian code")
> ```

Comment: hmm, shouldn't first line be like this: inserted_code = int(input("insert postcode: ")) ??

But it's weird, cause' in both ways it gives error for the first line

Comment: Sure, it's up to you to handle exception cases correctly. But my code should work for fair `int` input. Which exception do you catch? D you use `Python 3.X`?

Comment: I don't even know exactly, but I guess I use Python 2. I use Thonny to write a code.

Comment: execute please, `import platform;
print(platform.python_version())` to get it know

Comment: Then everything should work fine, send me exception please if it isn't

Comment: If I'll try to run the script, then it says:
>>> %Run inglisek.py
  File "C:\Users\Rehkli\Desktop\Python\inglisek.py", line 1
    inserted_code = input("insert postcode")
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected indent

Comment: @MartinRehkli, strongly recommend you watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cd-k6QQMa18  otherwise you will hit this exception very often during you start of programming on Python